# Canvas lines very unclean on some monitors

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, chart.js2

I use canvas for drawing lines, dots and the values for the dots. The values appear to be very unclean on some monitors, probably depending on their pixel density. Especially when I redraw the values a few times (my script redraws the values when the browser width gets below/above X pixels) the numbers get really frayed (jaggy?); maybe this is also some problem with the script. Still, the quality difference between the values on different monitors is shockingly high.

Left image is from a MacBook Pro 2016 (Retina) and right image is from a "standard 24" monitor". Is there a way to improve antialiasing or something similar?

Have some images:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's the redrawing that is causing the quality loss. Redrawing destroys the anti aliasing of the text. You need to clear the text before you redraw it, or avoid redrawing the value if it's already visible.

Comment: Thank you, I will try checking for that